# Safe following distance calculation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, word-problem

Two cars are stopped at a light. 
Car A is in the front. 
Car B is right behind it.
Distance between is zero.
Both cars are stopped. 
The light turns green.
Car A accelerates at constant rate of 1.
Car B must accelerate such that it is always 
exactly 3 times its velocity behind car A.
What is the function for the 
velocity of car B at time t?
(Car A obviously has velocity t at time t.
It also obviously has position 1/2 t squared at time t.)

Or:

stopped .  in front.  behind  , @ distance 0.  accelerates at constant rate of 1.  accelerates, being exactly 3 times its velocity behind  .  Solve for velocity of  at time t? (  obviously has velocity t at time t.)

Or by specifying position and velocity, can we solve over a non-trivial domain?

Equation of the form:
$$v+kv’=t$$

Seems to apply. What is solution?

$$v=t-k+ke^{-t/k}$$

The lead car always moves faster than the following car accept when they are both at rest.

The final question then is if there are $n$ cars, instead of just two, in line, what is the equation of motion for the last in line, car $n$?

Comment: What is your trying?

Comment: This inspired by the “safe following distance” rule of driving one car length back per 10 mph.

Comment: The only discontinuous part of this problem is the jerk or instant application of acceleration at t zero. This should not make the problem impossible, by itself.

Comment: Car B’s motion is described by the differential equation $t^2/2-x=3\dot x$.

Comment: Now if there are n cars in line, what is the formula for car n x in terms of t?

Comment: What is the relativistic solution in frame of reference of car B as v approaches c?

Comment: No wonder traffic moves so slowly.

Comment: Ok. All I need now is checking. Checks at t 0 and large.

Comment: Thank you everyone.

Comment: $t^2/8$ is not a solution to that differential equation.

Comment: You should write up your solution as an answer instead of adding it to the question so that the question isn’t left dangling as unanswered.

Comment: I think the confusion comes from lack of familiarity with the dot notation for time derivatives.

Comment: Sorry the dot was so small on my iPhone I did not see it.

Comment: You need more than 15 reputation to answer your own question. Until you’re there, I’d recommend leaving the answer in, as you had it before.

Comment: Incidentally, if you iterate this model you get a nice qualitative explanation of why the later cars in a line/convoy can be at a crawl even when the front car is moving at a good clip.

Comment: @amd Yes, I was thinking it explains the crawl. Now if we could just couple cars together dynamically, perhaps electronically, these limitations would be relaxed.

Comment: Would they, really, though? Even if the cars communicated with each other and responded to changing conditions at blinding electronic speed, their _mechanical_ systems will always have speed-independent delays, so they will still need to maintain a speed-dependent following distance, albeit a smaller one.

Comment: Yes very true. Even trains have slack in coupling. And who wants to be hit by a train? Not me!

Comment: $$\frac{-t^{n-1}-(n-1)kt^{n-2}+(n-1)!k^{n-2}te^{t/k}-n!k^{n-1}e^{t/k}}{(n-1)!k^{n-2}e^{t/k}}$$iff n large enough

Comment: The above is the velocity for car $n$. it works for $n >= 0$ It is exact solution of the iteration. I was able to find https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagel%E2%80%93Schreckenberg_model but it had no closed form solution!

Comment: Nice to note generalized factorial gives infinity for negative integers!

Comment: https://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9781461484349-c1.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-1444912-p175320688 Pipe’s model is (replaced?) by this and is solved here for car n. I do not find anyone else solving it.

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0191261501000108 But they won’t let me read it! I wonder if they have my equation, above?

Comment: When $n=0$, $v=t$; that is the equation for the pace car!! I had no idea the iteration would work that case; it works for all the cars!!

Comment: "it is always exactly 3 times its velocity behind car A".  Please explain.

Answer (score 2):

Let $s_a$ be the position of car $A$, with $0$ at the start.  Let $v_a$ be the speed of car $A$.  Let $s_b$ be the position of car $B$, measured from where $B$ starts, which means $s_a=s_b$ means the cars are touching. Let $v_b$ be the speed of car $B$.   Let $a_b$ be the acceleration of car $B$.

The speed of $A$ is $v_a=1t$, where the $1$ is the acceleration.
Its position is $s_a=\frac 12t^2$
We want $s_b=s_a-3v_b=\frac 12t^2-3v_b$
This is $3\frac {ds_b}{dt}+s_b=\frac 12t^2$ with $s_b(0)=0$
$s_b=\frac 12t^2-3t+9-9e^{-t/3}$ from [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3x%27%2Bx%3Dt%5E2%2F2)

For more cars, you follow the process down the line.  Solving the equation for the second car gives the input for the third car and so on.

Comment: The following distance must be based on the car in persuit.

Comment: See the closed form for car n in the comments.

Comment: @JohnLWinters;  My equation "We want" has the following distance $3v_b$.  It is based on the car in pursuit

Comment: Good. Now derive for car n.

Comment: Here https://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9781461484349-c1.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-1444912-p175320688 it is stated Pipes model was too hard to solve for n cars. My closed form solution is in the comments. It is difficult to copy into the answers.

Comment: The comment solution is a conjecture I made after studying a few instances of $n$. It needs proof, I suspect by induction.

Comment: Thank you for your derived solution for position.  I solved for velocity since my car has a speedometer that seems to respond more readily than my odometer.  Can you also derive a solution in closed form for car $$n$$?

Comment: Given a solution for position, you can just take a derivative to get a solution for velocity.  I haven't thought about more cars.  For the third car, you get the same $3s_c'+s_c=s_b$, so the right side is more complicated than for the second car, but the solution approach is the same.

Comment: I have velocity solution for car $n$ in the comments above